# Ionic how to read data from ble peripheral

Tags: android, ionic2, bluetooth-lowenergy, ionic-native

I have a big device that run android OS. idChamp® RS4 BLE RFID plug into that device. My user will use HID card to touch idChamp , I have to get serial number from HID card.
I tried some native lib

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-serial/

and

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ble/

but it still can’t catch anything after HID card touch idChamp. thank you for any help.